# How to pull updated files from a Heroku application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, discord.js

With a new Heroku hosted Discord Bot, changes are made to a file and I need that file when I make updates to the code, but I cannot get the updated file.

Previously I've tried a slug command and a clone command using Git with Heroku plugins to download these files, which both returned unhelpful.

The first command I tried was `git clone https://git.heroku.com/APP_NAME.git`, which returned an empty repository after I signed in with my API.

Then I tried `heroku slugs:download -a APP_NAME` which was successful and downloaded the repository, but it was the initial form of the Deployed build and did not contain the updated file.

My bot writes stats to users, examples are "money" and "daily" type things, to a `userData.json file`. I edit the bot locally, push it to GitHub, and deploy on Heroku from GitHub. When I try to downloaded Heroku's repository, I want the updated `userData.json` from the time the bot has been online so that when I make updates to the bot, I don't overwrite the new information with old information, however when using the clone command I get an empty repo, and when using `slugs:download` I get the repo that Heroku got when I first deployed the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My bot writes stats to users, examples are "money" and "daily" type things, to a `userData.json` file

This isn't a good strategy on Heroku, which has an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). File changes will be lost whenever your dyno restarts, and there isn't a good way to commit changes on Heroku and incorporate them into your repository.

Data typically doesn't belong in your repository. It's program state, which should be allowed to change from environment to environment. Save data in a database, not in a file.

[Heroku Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) is a relatively low-friction option that has a free tier to start. If you don't like PostgreSQL you can choose [another data store](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores).